# Flutter web tabbarview scrollcontroller not responding to keyboard scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-scrollbar

- I've created two tabs.
- In each tab I have SingleChildScrollView wrapped with Scrollbar.
- I can not have the primary scrollcontroller in both the tabs, because that throws me exception: "ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views."
- For Tab ONE I use primary scrollcontroller, for Tab TWO I created Scrollcontroller and attached it.
- For Tab ONE with primary scrollcontroller I can scroll both by keyboard and dragging scrollbar.
- But for Tab TWO with non primary scrollcontroller, I have to scroll only by dragging scrollbar. This tab doesn't respond to keyboard page up /down keys.

Please check my code below. Guide me on how to achieve keyboard scrolling for Tab TWO.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TabExample(),
    );
  }
}

class TabExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TabExampleState createState() => _TabExampleState();
}

class _TabExampleState extends State<TabExample> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Text('Tab ONE')),
              Tab(icon: Text('Tab TWO')),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            _buildWidgetA(),
            _buildWidgetB(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWidgetA() {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      children.add(
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWidgetB() {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      children.add(
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Scrollbar(
      controller: _scrollController,
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create an explicit `ScrollController` to achieve this.

One trick is to change which `SingleChildScrollView` is going to use the `PrimaryScrollController` whenever the `Tab` changes it's index.

So, when we listen that tab has changed to index 0, we will set that the first `SingleChildScrolView` is the `primary` one. When it changes to 1, we will set the other on as `primary`.

First create a new State variable like this,

```
int currentIndex = 0; // This will be the index of tab at a point in time
```

To listen to the change event, you need to add Listener to the `TabController`.

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Builder(  // <---- Use a Builder Widget to get the context this this DefaultTabController
    builder: (ctx) {

      // Here we need to use ctx instead of context otherwise it will give null
      final TabController tabController = DefaultTabController.of(ctx);

      tabController.addListener(() {
        if (!tabController.indexIsChanging) {

          // When the tab has changed we are changing our currentIndex to the new index
          setState(() => currentIndex = tabController.index);
        }
      });

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Text('Tab ONE')),
              Tab(icon: Text('Tab TWO')),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            _buildWidgetA(),
            _buildWidgetB(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Finally, depending on the `currentIndex` set `primary: true` to each `SingleChildScrollView`.

For `_buildWidgetA`,

```
Scrollbar(
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  showTrackOnHover: true,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    primary: currentIndex == 0,  // <--- This will be primary if currentIndex = 0
    child: Column(
      children: children,
    ),
  ),
);
```

For `_buildWidgetB`,

```
Scrollbar(
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  showTrackOnHover: true,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    primary: currentIndex == 1,  // <--- This will be primary if currentIndex = 1
    child: Column(
      children: children,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now, you should be able to control both of the tabs with your keyboard.

Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/0HZfd93v)

Comment: Thanks Nisanth. This works. I'm upvoting your answer. Waiting for other replies. If doesn't get better answer, will mark it as accepted answer. Curious, is it a bug in scrollcontroller? Should I report it to flutter?

Comment: @AshishKhurange I don't think this is a bug. It's just how it is implemented. You could also create your own `ScrollController`s but I think the difference is that you have to implement your own functionality to respond to keyboard events. It is definitely possible. Just a more harder route to solve this. That is why I didn't write that approach.