# Flutter web tabbar scroll issue with non primary scrollcontroller

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In continuation with [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757381/flutter-web-tabbarview-scrollcontroller-not-responding-to-keyboard-scrolling/67757771?noredirect=1#comment119770336_67757771)

The solution provided above is good. But hard for me to implement in my project.

Expected results:

- I've created two tabs.
- In each tab I have SingleChildScrollView wrapped with Scrollbar.
- I can not have the primary scrollcontroller in both the tabs, because that throws me exception: "ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views."
- For Tab ONE I use primary scrollcontroller, for Tab TWO I created Scrollcontroller and attached it.
- Widgets in both the tabs should be scrollabale using keyboard and mouse.

Actual results:

- For Tab ONE with primary scrollcontroller I can scroll both by keyboard and dragging scrollbar.
- But for Tab TWO with non primary scrollcontroller, I have to scroll only by dragging scrollbar. This tab doesn't respond to keyboard page up /down keys.
- When keyboard keys are used in Tab TWO actually contents of tab ONE are getting scrolled.

Check code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TabExample(),
    );
  }
}

class TabExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TabExampleState createState() => _TabExampleState();
}

class _TabExampleState extends State<TabExample> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Text('Tab ONE')),
              Tab(icon: Text('Tab TWO')),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            WidgetC(),
            WidgetD(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetC extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetC({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetCState createState() => _WidgetCState();
}

class _WidgetCState extends State<WidgetC>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<WidgetC> {
  List<Widget> children;
  @override
  void initState() {
    children = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      children.add(
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(child: Text('$i')),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scrollbar(
      key: PageStorageKey('WidgetC'),
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class WidgetD extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetD({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetDState createState() => _WidgetDState();
}

class _WidgetDState extends State<WidgetD>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<WidgetD> {
  List<Widget> children;
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    children = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      children.add(
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(child: Text('$i')),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scrollbar(
      key: PageStorageKey('WidgetD'),
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been accepted as a bug in flutter.
Pl follow for progress here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83711

Note for other developers facing same issue.
To overcome the mentioned problem, I changed my design layout. Instead of tabbar view I used Navigationrail widget. This solved my problem.
NavigationRail widget allowed me to attach primary scroll controller to multiple widgets without giving me exception: "ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views."
Sample code.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  WidgetC _widgetC = WidgetC();
  WidgetD _widgetD = WidgetD();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('NavigationRail Demo'), centerTitle: true),
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            elevation: 8.0,
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
            groupAlignment: 0.0,
            destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                label: Text('Tab ONE'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
                label: Text('Tab TWO'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
          // This is the main content.
          Expanded(
            child: _getPageAtIndex(_selectedIndex),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getPageAtIndex(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return _widgetC;
      case 1:
        return _widgetD;
    }
    return Container();
  }
}

class WidgetC extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetC({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetCState createState() => _WidgetCState();
}

class _WidgetCState extends State<WidgetC>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<WidgetC> {
  List<Widget> children;
  @override
  void initState() {
    children = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      children.add(
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
            child: Center(child: Text('$i')),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scrollbar(
      key: PageStorageKey('WidgetC'),
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class WidgetD extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetD({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetDState createState() => _WidgetDState();
}

class _WidgetDState extends State<WidgetD>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<WidgetD> {
  List<Widget> children;
//  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
//    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    children = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      children.add(
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
            child: Center(child: Text('$i')),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
//    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scrollbar(
      key: PageStorageKey('WidgetD'),
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
//      controller: _scrollController,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
//        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```